# flink : overlapping reading

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to implement an algorithm with the following access pattern (similar to the finite difference algorithm) :

[image: finite difference]

In this example, the first value of dataset_1 is used to calculate the first and the second value of dataset_2. So, I should have 2 different keys for this value.
Consequently, **some values** of dataset_1 **must be read several times** (2 or 3 times).

I think I have to use the `groupBy(key).reduce(Algorithm)` transformation, but I don't know how to define the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink DataSets are not ordered unless you process them in a single thread, i.e., with parallelism 1. You can how every add a sequential index to your data and use that index as a key.

From your example I assume that the value with index 4 of dataset_2 is computed from the values 3, 4, and 5 of dataset_1, i.e., each value of dataset_2 is derived from three (or two) values of dataset_1.

There are multiple ways to do what you want, some are easy to implement and others are more efficient.

An easy way to do what you want is to apply a `FlatMapFunction` on dataset_1 that emits each value with index `i` three times with three keys `i-1`, `i`, and `i+1`. After that you group the resulting data set on the new keys and use a GroupReduce function to compute the new value. This approach triples the data volume of dataset_1 but can be easily parallelized.

Another option is to do manual range partitioning, which is similar to the first approach but a bit more generic. I am again assuming that the values of dataset_1 have a sequential `idx` attribute. Use a FlatMapFunction to assign `partitionIds` to values, i.e., for a partition size of 100 elements do something like `partitionId = idx / 100`. The the first and last element of a partition need to be emitted twice. For example elements with `idx` 100 and 199 for partitionId 1 (values 100 to 199) need to be replicated to partitions 0 and 2 respectively, by emitting these values twice. Once `partitionIds` are assigned, you can `groupBy(partitionId)`, `sortGroup(idx)`, and `groupReduce` over all elements of a partition. The size of the partition is configurable.

Comment: I can't take the first solution because I can't triple the data for performance purpose. For the second solution, I don't see how to handle the overlapping reading. MapPartition gets the partition as Iterable (1 element at a time) but I need 2 or 3 elements of the input dataset. Could you, please, give an example showing the overlapping reading?

Comment: I extended the description of the range partitioning approach.

Comment: I understand now how we can use the partition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a sliding-window computation. You should us `DataStream` instead of `DataSet` and apply a window of size 3 and step size 1.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream dataset_2 = env.readTextFile(textPathTo-Dataset_1).window(Count.of(3)).every(Count.of(1)).WINDOW_FUNCTION(...).flatten();
```

There are multiple `WINDOW_FUNCTION` available (eg, mxn, min, sum or generic mapWindow, foldWindow, reduceWindow). Please look into the documenation which function fits your use-case: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/apis/streaming_guide.html

Comment: This solution would only work with a single thread (parallelism 1) if the order of the elements of dataset_1 is important, right?